# StartCoroutine method in not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this code 6 bubbles are used. They are scaled to a particular level amd then they are disappeared. Now the problem is that all the bubbles are coming at the same time. However it is required that they should come after some delay.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Display : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject bubble1;
public GameObject bubble2;
public GameObject bubble3;
public GameObject bubble4;
public GameObject bubble5;
public GameObject bubble6;
private int c=0;
private int z = 0;
private int[] a=new int[6];
private GameObject[] enlarge=new GameObject[6];
void Start ()
{
    int ch,t,k=0;
    string str="";
    float tim;
    GameObject[] bubble = {bubble1,bubble2,bubble3,bubble4,bubble5,bubble6};
    for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
    a = 0;
    str = "0";
    if(c==0)
    foreach(GameObject b in bubble)
    {
        b.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1F, 1F, 0F);
        str+=b.transform.tag;
    }
    c++;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {

        ch=0;
        while(true)
        {
            ch = Random.Range (0, 6);
            if (a [ch] == 0) 
            {
                a [ch] = 1;
                str+="2";
                break;
            } 


        }
        str+="3";
        t=-1;
        foreach(GameObject b in bubble)
        {
            t++;
            if(t==ch)
            {

                b.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1F, 1F, 0F);

                enlarge[k++]=b;

                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1F, 1F, 0F);
                StartCoroutine("waitthreesec");

            }
            str+="4";
        }

    }

}
IEnumerator waitthreesec()
{
    //print ("Thread");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);


    Debug.Log ("Just waited 10 second");
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    float tim;
    string str = "";
    Time.timeScale = 0.5F;
    print (Time.fixedTime+"");

    if(a[0]==1)
    {
        bubble1.transform.localScale =new Vector3(1F,1F,0F )* Time.time;

    }
    if(a[1]==1)
    {

        bubble2.transform.localScale =new Vector3(1F,1F,0F )* Time.time;    
    }
    if(a[2]==1)
    {
        //Time.timeScale = 0.5F;
        bubble3.transform.localScale =new Vector3(1F,1F,0F )* Time.time;
    }
    if(a[3]==1)
    {

        bubble4.transform.localScale =new Vector3(1F,1F,0F )* Time.time;
    }
    if(a[4]==1)
    {

        bubble5.transform.localScale =new Vector3(1F,1F,0F )* Time.time;
    }
    if(a[5]==1)
    {

        bubble6.transform.localScale =new Vector3(1F,1F,0F )* Time.time;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty, so let me elaborate first on what you did wrong before I paste the code.
**First of all you don't play very well with if/for C# syntax.**

If you use for/foreach that way, it will only execute first line of code below it:

```
foreach (var object in objects)
    DoStuff(object); //foreach will only execute this line per iterated object
    DoSomethingElse(); //foreach loop won't reach here, it will just execute after foreach loop is done
```

Proper way for multiline foreach/for is:

```
foreach (var object in objects)
{
    DoStuff(object);
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Same goes with if blocks:

```
if (c==0)
    DoStuff(); //will be executed only if c equals 0
DoSomethingElse(); // will be executed regardless c equals 0 or not
```

Also before posting please check if your code compiles, because it didn't before I started cleaning it up.

**Refactored code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Display : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bubble1;
    public GameObject bubble2;
    public GameObject bubble3;
    public GameObject bubble4;
    public GameObject bubble5;
    public GameObject bubble6;
    private int c = 0;
    private int z = 0;
    private int[] a = new int[6];
    private GameObject[] enlarge = new GameObject[6];

    void Start()
    {
        int ch, t, k = 0;
        string str = "";
        float tim;
        GameObject[] bubble = {bubble1, bubble2, bubble3, bubble4, bubble5, bubble6};

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {

            str = "0";
            if (c == 0)
            {
                foreach (GameObject b in bubble)
                {
                    b.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F);
                    str += b.transform.tag;
                }
                c++;
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {

                    ch = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        ch = Random.Range(0, 6);
                        if (a[ch] == 0)
                        {
                            a[ch] = 1;
                            str += "2";
                            break;
                        }


                    }
                    str += "3";
                    t = -1;
                    foreach (GameObject b in bubble)
                    {
                        t++;
                        if (t == ch)
                        {

                            b.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F);

                            enlarge[k++] = b;

                            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F);
                            StartCoroutine(waitthreesec()); //Instead of "waitthreesec", use waitthreesec() to avoid runtime overhead

                        }
                        str += "4";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    IEnumerator waitthreesec()
    {
        //print ("Thread");
        Debug.Log("Coroutine hit");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        Debug.Log("Just waited 2 seconds");
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float tim;
        string str = "";
        Time.timeScale = 0.5F;
        print(Time.fixedTime + "");

        if (a[0] == 1)
        {
            bubble1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F)*Time.time;

        }
        if (a[1] == 1)
        {

            bubble2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F)*Time.time;
        }
        if (a[2] == 1)
        {
            //Time.timeScale = 0.5F;
            bubble3.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F)*Time.time;
        }
        if (a[3] == 1)
        {

            bubble4.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F)*Time.time;
        }
        if (a[4] == 1)
        {

            bubble5.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F)*Time.time;
        }
        if (a[5] == 1)
        {

            bubble6.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 0F)*Time.time;
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to achieve what you're attempting, I'd go a little shorter way.

**For making each bubble pop one after another try:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Display : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Bubbles;

    void Start()
    {
        InitBubbles();
        StartCoroutine(PopBubbles()); //Instead of "PopBubbles", use PopBubbles() to avoid runtime overhead
    }

    public IEnumerator PopBubbles()
    {
        foreach (GameObject b in Bubbles)
        {
            b.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            while (Vector3.SqrMagnitude(Vector3.one - b.transform.localScale) > 0.05f)
            {
                b.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            b.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
        yield return null;
    }

    public void InitBubbles()
    {
        foreach (var bubble in Bubbles)
        {
            bubble.transform.localScale = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

A little note on how to use `Coroutines`:

- `Coroutine` will return control on each yield
- `yield return new WaitForSeconds(x)` will only make `Coroutine` return control and wait `x` seconds until caller can yield from it again

I've changed seperate field initializers into simple array, so you can initialize it that way:

[image]

Comment: Thank u for answering. But did u find any solution for StartCorountine method??

Comment: No it is not working. All the bubbles are appearing at the same time.

Comment: Alright, so it was both syntax and idea per se problem. I've added code how I would do it.

Comment: Mark it as an answered then. :)